# 子nodeが取得できない

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jquery Bonsai](https://github.com/aexmachina/jquery-bonsai) というプラグインを改造してjqueryのオリジナルプラグインを作成しています。

https://github.com/14021939/dropdownCheckCombobox

[dropdownCheckCombobox.js（96行目）](https://github.com/14021939/dropdownCheckCombobox)で、this.bonsaiの子nodeが取得できません。（コンソールでの出力ではObject[]になります。）

丸投げで本当に申し訳ありませんが、なぜなのかさっぱりわかりません。助けてください。

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザの開発者ツールでブレークポイントを設定してみると、次のようになりました。

[image: ss]

取得の仕方に問題があるわけではなく、実際その時点では `this.bonsai` の子要素は何もないです。しかし一通りスクリプトを実行した後で確認すると、ちゃんとそこにリストやチェックボックスが生成されています。となると、**チェックボックスが生成される前に上の処理が行われるのが問題** ということになります。

[`DropdownCheckCombobox.prototype.createBonsai`](https://github.com/14021939/dropdownCheckCombobox/blob/master/jquery.dropdownCheckCombobox.js#L59-L73) が以下のようになっていますよね。

```
this.bonsai = listTag.jsonList({
  url: self.options.dataUrl,
  onListItem: function(event, listItem, data, isGroup) {
    if(!isGroup){listItem.attr('data-value', data.id);}
  },
  onSuccess: function(event, jsonList)  {
      return $(this.el).find('> ol').bonsai({
        checkboxes: true,
        createInputs: 'checkbox',
        handleDuplicateCheckboxes: true,
        expandAll: true
      });
    }
});
this.handleCombobox();
```

`jsonList()` は url の読み込みを**非同期に**開始し、それ自身はすぐにreturnします。そして読み込みが完了したところで onSuccess を実行します。そのため、`$(this.el).find('> ol').bonsai()` はきちんと読み込み後に実行されますが、 `this.handleCombobox()` は読み込みを待たずに実行されてしまいます。

そして `onSuccess` の戻り値は使われないようなので、 `bonsai()` を return する意味はありません。

まとめると、`jsonList()` の `onSuccess` の中で、 `bonsai()` を実行した後に、 `handleCombobox()` を呼び出す必要がある、ということになります。こんな感じでしょうか。

```
this.bonsai = listTag.jsonList({
  url: self.options.dataUrl,
  onListItem: function(event, listItem, data, isGroup) {
    if(!isGroup){listItem.attr('data-value', data.id);}
  },
  onSuccess: function(event, jsonList)  {
      $(this.el).find('> ol').bonsai({
        checkboxes: true,
        createInputs: 'checkbox',
        handleDuplicateCheckboxes: true,
        expandAll: true
      });
      self.handleCombobox();
    }
});
```

`onSuccess` の中では this が別のものになっているので、 self を使うことに注意してください。